# Getting a file not found error when iterating over a directory

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to iterate through a file directory in the following way:

```
path = r'C:\my\path'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
     nodes_arr = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
```

And I get an error:

```
IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: 10028057_nodes not found.
```

When I try to print the files in the following way:

```
path = r'C:\my\path'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
```

I get a list and it contains all files in the directory, first one being "10028057_nodes" which provides the error...

Comment: Also, when executing nodes_arr = np.genfromtxt() with the path and file name in it, it works well (outside the loop, just for the specific file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the file names only. Python IO functions, whether called directly (`open`...) or through `numpy`, do not actually know that that these names reside in `path`. Unless your path is the current directory, which will what Python will assume, this will fail - since the said file name does not exist in the current directory.

What you need, is to concatenate the path to the file name, so:

```
nodes_arr = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(path, filename), delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the absolute path, like so:

```py
nodes_arr = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(path,filename), delimiter=',')
```

If you want your code to work then your python code file needs to be in the same folder where your other files are.

Comment: Please note this will fail when `path` does not end with the directory separator, which is often the case. You would need a `+'/'+` in the middle there on Linux, and `+'\\'+` on windows - better use `join`, that's safest.

Answer (score 0):

*os.listdir* gives you the name of the file, you still need to join the path in order to get its actual path.

```py
path = r'C:\my\path'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
     file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
     nodes_arr = np.genfromtxt(file_path, delimiter=',')
```